# Accessing cookies from outside POST request

Tags: python, post, cookies, flask

I am trying to access a cookie. I have been getting along quite well with

```
request.cookies.get('cookiename')
```

which works as it should. That is when the `request` part of that line is coming from the app itself (me). However, I am receiving a POST request via a webhook. The POST request is not originating from me. So, when I try and do

```
request.cookies.get('cookiename')
```

or even

```
request.cookies
```

I get back `None` and `{}`, respectively. I assume this is because the request object (which does not come from me) doesn't have any cookies. Which makes sense. Is there a way to receive the request, and resend it to myself so that the request come from me, giving me access to my cookies? or should I be able to access my cookies in an alternative way. Not really sure how to go from here. Thanks in advance for anyone who can shed some light onto this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the method is `request.COOKIES.get('name', '')`. Try it, and test.

Comment: No, that will not work. `request.cookies` is a dict of all of the cookies stored within the request. When sending my _own_ POST request to access the cookies, the dict is full of whatever cookies I have in it. `{'mycookie': 'mycookievalue'}` However, when using an _outside_ source's POST request, the request object does not correspond with my request object/cookies. So the dict for the outside's POST `request.cookies` is `{}`.